# Is it unethical to take a photograph of my question sheets from a sit-down exam I've just finished if I am not allowed to take them home?

Tags: ethics, exams, social-skills

Last semester I've retaken a course and went through the exam. It was a sit-down exam and all students were present. All students are required put their possessions (phones, cameras, etc.) in their bags and put their bags in front of the room.

The students were not allowed to take the question sheets home.

As I was retaking the course, I feel the need to take a documentation to review my answers and to understand the problems better. So AFTER the exam was finished, I take my bag, grab my camera, and then I asked the supervisor (as the lecturer was not present at the site) whether I was allowed to take a photograph or not while gesturing to show my camera (which I had just taken out of my bag). **It was denied and I complied without complaining**.

Then I told my friend about that incident. He was quite surprised that I complied with that. He told me that he would take the photograph anyway for his advancement in learning, which he said it would be for the greater good but **I can't actually spread / redistribute them as it would break the concept of exam itself**.

The usual practice in my campus is that if the question sheets are allowed to be taken home, some students would scan and put them into a compilation and share them to the younger students to study and ponder upon as they will get different sets of questions.

Other than that, students that absent at the exam can take it at a different appointed time with a different set of questions.

So I'm stumped whether I should have taken the photograph or not. I thought it was unethical to take it if taking the sheet home is prohibited, but then my friends thought made me reconsider. If I took the photograph I would not create an unfair advantage for those who took the exam at a different date (if there are any) anyway.

PS: I'm sorry if I attracted heated discussions. And I think there is a misconception here. I don't intend to question the rule itself or trying to deceive myself. I only want to know how ethics and etiquette work as I was quite an anti-social from my childhood and I want to start learning about social life. I also didn't intend to redistribute the photograph at that moment.

PS2: My campus was located in Indonesia. I hope this will help to consider the problem at hand

PS3:

The rule was actually enforced by the Department. It would also be enforced to graduate students (and to postgraduate students IF they have any sit-down exams)

.

My friend which I mentioned above was in fact a graduate student.

The guidelines mentioned not to ask "Undergraduate-specific issues that could not apply to graduate or post-graduate academicians". As this question is also applicable to (at least) graduate students, I think this question is quite appropriate for Academia SE. But if it's still deemed as an inappropriate question by many and was closed because of it, then I'll just accept the closure.

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. I am somewhat skeptical that you actually want to ask what you are asking, as the ethicality of the situation is straightforward to me (you gain an advantage by breaking the rules). I presume that you want to ask about something like the general purpose and ethicality of **imposing** such a rule, copying exams in the absence of such a rule, or disseminating old exams. If this is the case, please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: In most examinations I'm aware of, having a camera or a phone on your person during an examination is prohibited and can lead to  the exam being tainted.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I don't intend to question the ethicality of imposing such rule. I only mean to ask whether it was ethical to actually take that photograph.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 In my campus all students' bags should be put at the front of the room so nobody can't get access to whatever tools the brought during the exam. That's why I have the mean to take that photograph after the exam was finished.

Comment: Vote to close - this is an unclear question, but most interpretations lead to the conclusion that this is inappropriate for this site.

Comment: @PatrickSanan May I know why would my question regarded as inappropriate while I meant to ask about Ethical Academic Conduct? Well, as this is Academia SE, I think this is the right place to ask.

Comment: It's not relevant to academics, only to students. Please don't take the number of upvotes you got as an indication of quality, and see the guidelines http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @PatrickSanan Umm.. I wasn't referring to the points though. As for the student part, the same issue actually happened to graduate and post-graduate students in my lab as the same rule is applied to them too because it was in fact enforced by the department (which I knew of later on). So I think the question is applicable to them too. And my friend I mentioned above is a graduate student. Perhaps I should have mentioned those, but the guidelines only prohibited questions that are not applicable to graduate or post-graduate students.

Comment: One sheet is easy to memorize. What's the problem?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

**Taking a photo is effectively equivalent to taking the question sheet home.**

For either of these: it’s not inherently a bad thing, and (as your friend said) it can be good for personal study, and so on.  However, it can be used for unethical purposes (passing the questions on to students who haven’t taken the exam yet), so the school have prohibited it.  Given this, it *is* unethical, since it’s breaking a rule (and, moreover, a reasonably justified rule).

If the rules happen to be written in such a way that they just prohibit “taking the sheets home” and didn’t mention photos, then taking a photo may be allowed by the rule as written, but it is clearly still violating the intention of the rule.

So **yes, the supervisor’s ruling was reasonable, and you were right to comply with it.**

**Edit.**  There is, however, no problem with politely emailing the instructor afterwards and asking if you can get a copy of the exam (or parts of it).  No need to mention ethics or taking photos in the email; just say that you’d be grateful to have a copy for your own studying, if the instructor is willing to share it.  Maybe the instructor will say yes; maybe no; maybe “yes, but not until next week”.  But provided you are polite, and ready to accept a possible refusal, then I don’t think there can be any harm in asking.

Comment: Is it also unethical even if the students who take the exam at a different date are guaranteed to get a different set of question? Please don't be offended. I'm just curious.

Comment: The professor didn't return the question sheets SPECIFICALLY to prevent distribution.  This is well within the rights of the professor, and not within your rights to evade.  Attempts to circumvent this are ethically questionable.

Comment: @ScottSeidman So that's how it is. I really forgot that it was within the professor's right to do so. Whether the other students get different sets of questions or not is irrelevant then. Thank you... :)

Comment: > *it is clearly still violating the intention of the rule* Is the intent stated in the rule? For all I know, the rule could stem from need to actually get those papers back, because of some weird environmental legislation (we recycle 100% of our paper, yay!) or someone toying with six sigma or whatever. Taking a photo does not remove the sheet from the school, so it's **NOT** equivalent to taking the sheet home. What about coming home and writing down that task you've struggled with but could not solve? What about discussing that task with a friend?

Comment: @Daerdemandt Occam's Razor. The rule is probably meant to prevent distribution. If you want to question whether it is, ask the teacher in question (as the OP did) don't assume there's a contrived reason for the rule

Comment: @Jasper *I* don't assume a specific reason for the rule, question's author does. Assuming that prof. really intends to prevent distribution via getting papers back strikes me as disingenuous towards the prof. You expose papers to students - you consider those papers leaked. If you *know* rule's intent then please share the source so we can stop guessing. Besides, if the rule's intent was to prevent distribution then emailing the prof and asking for a copy is pretty pointless, and distributing would be prohibited explicitly.

Comment: @Daerdemandt: actually, it was your first comment that prompted me to add the edit suggesting an email.  I agree with you, the reason could be something completely different, like recycling, or (more likely in my opinion) could be just to *temporarily* prevent distribution (if some students are sitting the exam a few days late), and so in that case the instructor may well be happy to send a copy afterwards.  My answer aims to be reasonable advice for either possibility.

Comment: I would add that the OP's mention of the difficulty of the course is irrelevant to the actual question.  I bring this up because students (at least in some studies I've read) rationalize academic misconduct when they perceive the task as difficult, or tedious, or not worth the time it would take to do it honestly.

Comment: While I agree with the email in principal, I would advise against the OP sending an email in this case. OP already attempted to get the questions out of the exam session, and was denied. Asking again, regardless of how polite you are would at best raise an eyebrow from the professor, if not immediately make them angry.

Comment: @krillgar I would disagree, for one reason.  The OP keeps talking about "the supervisor", which to me implies the person he asked isn't the instructor.  I think it's very possible the TA/proctor isn't permitted to let the students take home the test, but the instructor might be willing to, once everyone's finished taking make-up tests, if they were late.

Comment: @PatrickM I asked the exam supervisor as the lecturer was not present at the site

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Ah, yes... When I read my my post again, I think the difficulty part doesn't actually contribute to explaining my problem and my intent. Sorry for the confusion. I'll edit that.

Comment: @PLL Thank you for your suggestion in the edit. Perhaps it is the best course of action I could take. :)

Comment: If we say "Taking a photo is effectively equivalent to taking the question sheet home." then that leads to it is clearly wrong.  However, if we say "Taking a photo is effectively equivalent to memorizing the question sheet." then it is clearly OK.

Comment: @emory I think we have to consider it closer to taking the sheet home.  Memorization is a mental device for getting the information off the sheet.  Taking a photo and taking the sheet home are both physical methods of getting the information off the sheet.  Considering the memory one is the only one with inherent uncertainty in keeping the information, I don't think it's appropriate to link that with physical methods.

Answer (score 14):

The contents of the blank exam, including the questions/formatting/instructions/etc., belong to the person who wrote it.  This person retains copyright and all associated rights, unless otherwise given away (or unless otherwise claimed by the employer).

It is irrelevant why the exam's author does not want to permit photography of the exam.  Perhaps the author intends to create a book (or paper or patent), in part with this material.   Or, perhaps, as the OP speculates, the author intends to create a future exam, in part with this material.  Relinquishing a copy of the exam questions may make any of these more difficult in the future.

In the OP's question, the student is granted permission to read the exam, and write answers in the designated areas.  However, this does not mean that the student is granted additional rights, such as keeping the exam questions, or photographing them.  Doing so infringes on the exam author's intellectual property; doing so after being told not to is a flagrant infringement.  It would be very difficult to build a persuasive case that doing so is not unethical.

Comment: This does not fall within the domain of copyright as the exam is not redistributed or copied any further. Now, the question is not about the lawfulness but about ethics, but the ethical backbone of copyright is avoiding economic damage to the copyright holder. Nothing that the asker intended to do would cause such a damage. A similar thing applies to intellectual property: Unless the asker claims that the exam is their intellectual property, this is not touched. (BTW: With your arguments it would also be illegal or unethical to take photographs of almost anything created by a human.)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft It seems plausible to me that copyright law would cover this circumstance, because taking a photo of something on a piece of paper does make a copy of that content - this is basically what a photocopier does, after all. Taking a photo of a building or sculpture or some arbitrary object would not be similarly equivalent to making a copy. Of course, then you could get into a fair use defense, which might plausibly excuse taking a picture of e.g. a painting, and might or might not be applicable here.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Actually yes, taking photo of a building is copyright infringement e.g. in France, Belgium or Italy. Some countries have "fair use" clause that allows you to make a copy for personal use and/or under specific conditions, but it's highly dependent on local laws. If that legislation is unethical in your opinion then fight to change it, but telling people on the internet that copyright doesn't apply is pretty much encouraging to break law.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft No. Copyright subsists in any creative work, whether or not it is intended for distribution and whether or not the author intended to charge for distribution. This most definitely includes exams. The distinction between written works and, say, a building is that a photograph of a written work is a copy of that work, whereas a photograph of a building is just a picture of the building, not a copy of the building.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I am not debating that the exam is not subject to copyright. I am debating whether copyright applies to the action in question. At least in German copyright (which is structured to explicitly allow and disallow things), I am pretty certain that it doesn’t. In US copyright, e.g., has a fuzzy fair-use clause, it’s also more fuzzy what *the domain* of copyright is – well, I grant you that. Either way, compare to the following cases: Writing down the text of the exam from memory; taking a photograph of a published exam; taking a photograph of a public poster.

Comment: @wrzlprmft, suppose the course instructor wants to publish a book "50 exams for use in course X".  This book would not sell as well if copies of the exams were already known.  Hence there is (potentially) direct economic damage caused by taking that photograph.

Comment: @vadim123: … if you disseminate the photograph (or the contents of the exam). **That** (not taking the photograph) would be a clear violation of copyright. But that is not what the asker intended to do.

Comment: This answer is just plain wrong. There's almost no question that taking a copy for temporary, personal additional study of an exam one has taken would be fair use. This is simply *not* a legal issue and answering it as if it was one makes no sense.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, in the US at least, fair use has been eroded by the courts to be almost negligible.  However, even with a very broad reading of "fair use", a photocopy of the entirety of the exam would not pass the "Amount or Substantiality of the Portion Used" factor of fair use.  A photocopy of a single question might be okay.

Comment: @vadim123 I completely disagree. Fair use is quite broad in a non-commercial context like this one. And, in any event, that's just one factor -- pretty much all the other factors weigh in favor of a finding of fair use.

Comment: Note that the OPS original statement involved photographing for the purpose of redistribution

Comment: @ScottSeidman That's a closer case, but still all of the fair use factors but that one (that the whole work is taken) weigh in favor of it being fair use, so it almost certainly would still be considered fair use. This still isn't a legal issue.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Well, objectively speaking I could always do that, but at that time I didn't intend to redistribute to other people (students). Perhaps I should reword my explanations better.

Comment: The ethics and even the morality of copyrights - a legal practice based on collusion between monarchies and oligopolic publishers from the middle-ages - are debatble in themselves; so an argument based on the ethical/moral validity of copyrights is, IMO, not the right one to make. Others have argued convincingly against the ethics of this action directly, regardless of copyrights.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft All 3 of your examples are copyright infringements. Fair use may or may not exclude them. You're German, ask Piratenpartei, they have nice examples of how ridiculous copyright can be. Doesn't make it any less valid.

Comment: @einpoklum Law can be viewed as codified ethic, therefore if something breaks law there is high chance it's unethical. We're not debating morality of copyrights (you are), we're debating if this situation violates copyright because it affects it's ethics.

Comment: @Agent_L: I am rather familiar with German copyright law, and copying a text for private purposes is explicitly and clearly allowed under [§ 53 (1) UrhG](//www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_urhg/englisch_urhg.html#p0297). By the way: According to the sources I could find, it’s not illegal to take photographs of copyrighted buildings in France, Italy, and Belgium, it’s only forbidden to distribute photographs or similar.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Yes, and the point is that every country has different scope of allowed use. BTW, in the age of Facebook a private use without rights to distribute is pretty much useless.

Comment: @Agent_L: Law _can_ be viewed as codified ethic, but I don't think that it should; and even if I did, then 2. It's the ethics of other people in other social classes at other times and with other interests codified by other people with other interests again.

Comment: Copyright law may also be relevant for a different reason.  Sometimes, when I compose a question paper for an exam, I include an image or data table reproduced (with attribution, of course) from a published source.  Here in the UK, I'm protected from legal action in connection with this by section 32 of the Copyright, Designs and Patents Act 1988.  Section 32 was amended in 2003 and again in 2014, in such a way that, between 2003 and 2014, the protection applied only if I forbade students from taking copies of the question paper out of the examination hall.

Answer (score 12):

If you would have taken that photograph, you would have broken a rule to gain an advantage: Even if the exam is not repeated exactly, you gain information as on what kind of questions to expect and you state yourself that you want to use the photographs to your advance (even if this involves honest learning). Taken the photograph would thus have been unfair against those students who comply with the rules and do not have this advantage. This would clearly be unethical.

As the exam is not repeated exactly and the same can be achieved with memorising, you may debate over *how* bad taking a photograph would be. Also you can debate whether the examinor’s approach to exams – relying on the contents being kept secret to some extent – is a good and effective one. All of this does not however impeach the ethicality of taking a photograph. If you do not agree with the rules, complain about the rules first; do not just break them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The second paragraph is a real eye opener. I've never considered that approach at all. :)

Comment: Part of my math exam was a test. All the questions, that might be in the test, were public for whole semester. For those, who wanted to memorise the answers, there was little surprise. It was 12 000 questions.

Comment: While I whole-heartendly disagree with the last sentence, I agree with the rest of the second paragraph.

Comment: @einpoklum: The last sentence has two parts, so a whole-hearted disagreement means that you think there are situations in which you do not agree with the rules but should not complain and yet should break them. I don't understand why, as long as we're talking about rules that are not inherently unethical themselves.

Comment: I disagreed with the combination of the two parts, i.e. "if (don't-agree) then {do complain; don't break}". In my opinion, you should complain about them when appropriate, and break them when appropriate or necessary. And - it is indeed appropriate or necessary. Example: In my alma mater, they were about to enact this rule precluding people from using the bathroom during exams except during one break in the middle. We (the grad student union) protested, but were ignored. Consequently, we announced that...

Comment: (cont) ... we were rejecting that rule outright, and that we would back anyone who would be penalized in any way for using the bathroom when he/she needed to.

Comment: @einpoklum: Just to confirm, for your "complain and break" case you are referring to rules that you consider unethical, right? Your bathroom example seems to fit into this category. If so then I think we actually don't disagree; just misunderstood one another.

Comment: @einpoklum: Added one word to make this less general.

Comment: @user21820: That would be the typical case. But sometimes, you can't be expected to complain. When the regime (of a state, a university, a department, or even a PI in a lab) has a vindictive streak, and would hold a grudge against whoever complains.

Comment: @einpoklum: Agreed, sadly. But I'd say your kind of rule-breaking is not anywhere near the norm! If there were more of your kind and less of the usual kind then the world will probably be a better place because those same rule-breakers will not discard rules altogether but put new better rules into place.

Answer (score 2):

Just a comment too long to be posted as comment.

Even the instructor allowed, I would still suggest you not to do it. If for any reason the questions are leaked (your phone got stolen or hacked, or other people get to see your questions), you'll automatically become a prime suspect. And worse, even the questions were not leaked through you but through other channels, you'll still likely be included in the suspect list.

This can create a lot of troubles, the instructor will have to remake the exam. And in rare case all the students might have to retake due to possible mass cheating... the list can go on and on.

Your friend's argument that "he would take the photograph anyway for his advancement in learning, which he said it would be for the greater good" is flawed. First, knowing how to answer a set of exam questions is really not that much more beneficial than knowing how to answer a set of textbook questions or other published/released quiz questions, etc. Second, the benefit of getting this one extra piece of study material is far outweighed by the aforementioned risks and harms.

If you're concerned about how you performed, you can always try to communicate with the instructor or TA to discuss your approaches after the grade is released.

Answer (score 1):

These rules often exist to prevent students from making public the exam questions. Unfortunately, there are some Web sites that will publish such exam sheets, and sometimes even pay students to do so.

When I was teaching, that particular school re-used the same exams on all campuses, and for several years. I'm not commenting on whether this is a good idea, but that's the way it was. We did find a few of our exams on such a Web site.

Comment: Hi, Kevin. Thanks for responding to my old question. At that time, I already got a solution. You see, my goal was to get some materials to review on my own, right? Then I won't be needing the photograph, since I can just ask the lecturers for some reviewing materials. I admit, this would have been a simple problem, but I thought about it too much and forgot my goal.

Comment: @WidiWidiyanto Totally understood, and a legitimate request. I didn't mean to say that *you* were doing it, just that one out of a thousand students might, and just to prevent that, we had to control distribution of the exams for everybody.

Answer (score 0):

If a rule was clearly unfair, then you'd have grounds to protest. Like if the rule said that white students are allowed to make copies of the test but black students are not, there'd be pretty obvious grounds for complaint.

But barring that, it is surely fair to expect everyone to comply with the rules, whether they like the rule or not. Whether I was the prof or another student, I'd consider it totally unacceptable for someone to say, "I didn't see a good reason for this rule, so I broke it." It is certainly fair and reasonable to ask the purpose of a rule. But it is not justified to break a rule just because you don't see the purpose. Maybe you're not smart enough to understand, or not creative enough, or haven't thought through all the possible scenarios. Heck, maybe you're not dishonest enough to see how others could take advantage.

And realistically, if breaking the rule does not give you some advantage, then why did you want to break it? If you break the rule and others follow it, then you have an unfair advantage.

One could argue that if the intent is to prevent distribution, the rule is ineffective, because a student could surely remember at least some of the questions and pass this information on. But you could say the same of any rule or security measure. If the tests are kept in a locked file drawer before testing day, someone might break into the office and steal a copy. If students are prohibited from getting help during an exam, someone might have a miniature radio in his ear with his friend giving tips. Etc. The fact that it is possible for others to break the rules does not justify you breaking the rules.

Comment: "Students with photographic memory are allowed to retain a copy of the exam but those who rely on paper as a memory aid are not"

Comment: @BenVoigt That sounds like the starting of the Xmen's Mutant Registration Act. ;)

Comment: @krillgar: I'm just pointing out that the rule IS clearly unfair and discriminatory, unless all examinees are subjected to [neuralyzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuralyzer) when leaving the exam room.

Comment: @BenVoigt Well, okay. But by that reasoning, history tests are discriminatory because students with good memories for dates and places get good grades while students with poor memories get bad grades.

Comment: @Jay: There's a reasonable argument that such history tests are *discriminating*, rather than discriminatory - their explicit purpose is to discriminate between students with good memories for dates and places and those with bad memories for the same. There's a reasonable argument that history should be about more than *just* dates and places, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz Umm, yes, of course. That was supposed to be a witty reply to BenVoight.

Comment: "It is surely fair to expect everyone to comply with the rules" - no, not surely. I would not expect people to comply with unfair rules. Now, you argue "barring clearly unfair etc." - I would say otherwise. You can expect complaince only with clearly-fair rules. This rule was at least puzzling and somewhat problematic (including for people who find it fair, see @Wrzlprmft's answer), and some people might find it wholly unfair. It is not reasonable to expect compliance in such situations without prior discussion.

Comment: @einpoklum: Sorry but I think you've not thought through carefully enough about fairness. A murderer who intentionally kills people for fun might consider unfair a law that judges them to be wrong. But are you saying that it is unreasonable to expect them to comply with the law? If not, then clearly you cannot just determine 'fairness' of a rule in terms of the person subject to the rule. A much more developed moral framework is necessary.

Comment: @user21820: If the prevalence of people who kill for fun is not negligible, then, yes, it is unreasonable to expect a large group of people to not kill people. That is not to say that this kind of action would be justifiable. But - you're using a straw man, or straw murderer, argument here. Students often do expect to be able to get a copy of the exam questions (whether the expectation is valid or not).

Comment: @einpoklum: I now see that you interpret the word "[un]reasonable" differently. I and likely many others interpret it to mean "[un]justifiable" when the context suggests it. My straw murderer was not actually straw, because it was based on a misunderstanding of your interpretation of "reasonable".

Comment: @user21820: relevant "[dictionary definition of "reasonable"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unreasonable). I think the definition only agrees with my interpretation... regardless, perhaps you could edit your answer and make your interpretation more explicit.

Comment: @einpoklum: Various dictionaries at http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reasonable agree with me that "reasonable" can be used to mean "fair / acceptable" in suitable contexts. I'm a native speaker too, but I agree we could be more precise by using less ambiguous words. However, I'm just a commenter and neither answer belongs to me. =)

Comment: @einpoklum If people only obey rules that, in their opinion, are unquestionably fair, that's pretty much synonymous with "there are no rules". If I think something is fair and reasonable I'll presumably do it whether there's a rule requiring it or not. So you're saying the standard should be, Everybody does whatever he feels like. Or even if you wouldn't take it that far, there's a huge difference between protesting rules that you believe to be unfair and calling for discussion, and simply ignoring them. ...

Comment: ... How would you react if you were a student, and you thought some rule was fair and reasonable and so you followed it, and you later found out that some other student broke the rule and gained an advantage, and he said, "well, I didn't think the rule was fair so I ignored it"?

Comment: @Jay: You're mis-interpreting my statements, creating a false dichotomy, and making a leap from "people cannot fairly be expected to follow rules which they don't think are fair" to "everybody does whatever he feels like". In the case of your example: 1. I reject the artificially competitive mentality, as though academic studies are supposed to be about gaining advantages over others and 2. If s/he is able to make a cogent argument of that kind then most likely it's also somewhat valid anyway. Why are you looking for the worst in people?

Comment: @einpoklum While school is not all about competition, there is an element of competition to it that cannot be ignored in this context. If Al follows the rules and flunks out of school while Bob breaks the rules and gets a degree, Bob could have better job opportunities than Al. Etc.

Comment: @einpoklum "If s/he is able to make a cogent argument" If a student can make a persuasive argument to the professor or the administration, sure, by definition. But the context is a student breaking rules that he in his opinion considers unfair, after the prof rejected the argument. People often have great ability to justify unethical actions TO THEMSELVES.

Comment: @Jay: If you noticed him doing it, then ask him for justification. If you haven't noticed then it's all a theoretical discussion anyway since you can't do anything about it.

Comment: @einpoklum But the context here is, he asked the prof for permission, the prof said no, his friend now says he should have done it anyway. So presumably if someone saw him do it and asks for justification, he's going to give the same argument that he already gave to the prof and that the prof rejected. And BTW, if something is unethical, it isn't made ethical by the fact that no one saw you do it.

Comment: I wasn't arguing the specifics, I was objecting to your general claim about what's "surely fair to expect. But in this specific case - the student made a fair attempt to appeal the rule, was rebuffed and gave it up; I don't see the problem. As for the BTW - if something is ethical, you are not obliged to convince people who believe otherwise of that fact in order for it to remain ethical.